# How to generate a vector of random numbers knowing the standard deviation and the mean (matlab)?

Tags: matlab, random

I would like to generate a vector of 20 random numbers knowing the standard deviation, the mean and contaning two 0 values. Is it possible?

These are the desired values of mean and standard deviation:
Mean: 3.3
Standard deviation: 25%

This seems to work fine: https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/random-numbers-with-specific-mean-and-variance.html however, I need to have in my vector two 0 values.

Comment: Where are the two 0 values in the array? Beginning, end or their place is random?

Comment: exactly two zeros or at least two zeros? Also unclear why you've given std dev as a percentage

Comment: It doesn't actually really matter, so it can be random.

Comment: At least two zeros

Comment: You need to specify the desired _distribution_. Knowing the mean, the standard deviation and two values is not enough

Comment: Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30303/how-to-simulate-data-that-satisfy-specific-constraints-such-as-having-specific-m

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a few steps, as detailed in the comments. The "at least" two zeros condition is easier than "exactly" two zeros would be - in the latter case you would have to write a quick function to return `randn` values except zero and then make sure the distribution shifting doesn't create new zeros.

```
% Create an array of length N+z (=20 here), which is N=18 randn values and z zeros
% Could make this more complicated to limit/expand on specific values
N = 18;
z = 2;
v = [randn(N,1); zeros(z,1)];
% Define a target mean (mu) and standard dev (sd)
mu = 3.3;
sd = 25;
% We have to iterate several times (100 is arbitrary) to get closer to both
% the s.d. and mean criteria. More passes for arbitrary accuracy
for ii = 1:100
    % Scale the vector to satisfy the standard dev
    v = sd*v/std(v);
    % Shift the vector to satisfy the mean, but only the non-zero randn values
    v(1:N) = v(1:N) - mean(v(1:N)) + ((N+z)/N)*mu;
end

% Output check
fprintf( 'Standard dev: %.4f\nMean: %.4f\n', std(v), mean(v) );
% >> Standard dev: 25.0000
% >> Mean: 3.3000
```

Note that by forcing specific values this isn't necessarily a perfectly normally distributed set of numbers any more, but it does satisfy your mean and standard deviation conditions. This is an issue with your problem statement - any solution will have this footnote.

Comment: Thank you for your anwser. Is it normal that in the final vector I don't have the two zeros?

Comment: Indeed, there is an algorithm to generate two _Bernoulli_ variates with a given mean and standard deviation; see e.g., Devroye, Non Uniform Random Variate Generation, p. 690.

Comment: @GiuliaLombardi I've edited my answer to retain the two zeros, I had missed that the mean shifting altered them originally

Comment: Technically this won't be normally distributed, nor would it work for any other continuous distribution, because the probability of getting any specific value (let alone two occurrences) is zero for continuous distributions.

Comment: @pj I already said this in the answer, and it's an issue with the task not my implementation